# RUBY ISSUE: mysql2 0.5.4 with a mysql in a docker container how to connect the two

Tags: ruby, docker, mysql2

So I'm on Ubuntu 22.... mysql 5.7 in the official docker container.
I'm attempting to install mysql2 ruby gem however it is looking for libraries that I believe are in the container and not in the host directory structure...

```
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... no
```

Opinions on way to do to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Install the MySQL client development package (`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` on Debian-ish systems) where your Ruby is. The Ruby MySQL gem needs them and cannot function without them. If you cannot use `sudo`, you can [compile the necessary libraries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html) yourself. The third option is to move your Ruby code into a container too.

Comment: Thanks I was able to install the libraries...is there any way to get the host to recognize the libraries in the docker?

Comment: I don't think so. They are basically two different computers, for most intents and purposes.